# find the smallest number in a array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, minimum

i'm trying to write a function to find the smallest number on an array of an array.

already tryed this, but i don't really know how to do when there is arrays on an array.

```js
const arr = [4, 8, 2, 7, 6, 42, 41, 77, 32, 9]
const min = Math.min(arr)
console.log(min)
```

Comment: You want the smallest number per array (`[[1,2],[3,4]] -> [1,3]`), or all of them (`[[1,2],[3,4]] -> 1`)?

Comment: the smallest number of all of them

Comment: You should add this information, and an example of a real input (array of arrays) in the question. I'm pretty sure @Andy would have posted a different answer if this would have been part of the question from the beginning.

Comment: He certainly would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use spread `...` and `flat`:

```js
const a = [[0, 45, 2], [3, 6, 2], [1, 5, 9]];

console.log(Math.min(...a.flat()));
```

Or you might use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [[7, 45, 2], [3, 6, 2], [1, 5, 9]];

let r = arr.reduce((a, e) => Math.min(a, ...e), Infinity) 

console.log(r);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz, I added another option.

Answer (score 4):

By taking ES6, you could use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which takes an array as arguments.

```js
const arr = [4, 8, 2, 7, 6, 42, 41, 77, 32, 9];
const min = Math.min(...arr);

console.log(min);
```

With ES5, you could take [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which take [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and the parameters as array.

```js
const arr = [4, 8, 2, 7, 6, 42, 41, 77, 32, 9];
const min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);

console.log(min);
```

For unflat arrays, take a flatten function, like

```js
const
    flat = array => array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(Array.isArray(a) ? flat(a) : a), []),
    array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    min = Math.min(...flat(array));

console.log(min);
```

Comment: This work fine, buti need to do the same thing for multiple arrays like that    array=[[1,2][3,4]]

Comment: The spread syntax allows any iterable object (like an array) to be expanded. It not only works with arrays.

Comment: why not simply use `arr.reduce((r,a) => r.concat(...a))` ?

Comment: @d9ngle, it woks not for deep nested arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the nested arrays and then use [`Math.min(...array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) on each to get the minimum. The output from `map` is an array of minimum values.

```js
const arr = [[4, 8, 2], [7, 6, 42], [41, 77, 32, 9]];

const out = arr.map(a => Math.min(...a));

console.log(out);
```